# Whats a word for a person who pretends to be a administrator?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

For example,

> person 1 is in a forms website and breaks the rules. 
>   Person 2 who is not a administrator tries to imposternate being one by informing the rules.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! That's a very good question. For single-word-requests it is considered goo practice to provide a sentence with a gap for the word. I your case, you might extend your existing quote with the sentence "Person 2 is a ___", since your quote does a very good job of explaining your request already.

Comment: "Imposternate" is not a recognised word. The verb from which the noun "impostor" is derived is "impose". And "imposter" is "one who imposes on others" (OED). However the way in which "impostor" is used has moved on so that unlike its verb of origin carries a more specific sense than "impose". However "impostor" could be the answer you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who pretends to be something they are not is an *imposter*

From Dictionary.com

> **[Imposter](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/imposter?s=t)** or im·post·er [im-pos-ter] *noun*
>
> 1. a person who practices deception under an assumed character, identity, or name.

This applies to the act of pretending to be someone else.  In this case, unless he clearly said he WAS an adminstrator, he may just be a *Stickler*

> **[Stickler](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stickler?s=t)** [stik-ler] *noun*
>
> 1. a person who insists on something unyieldingly (usually followed by for)

In this case, he could be a stickler for the rules.

Either way, unless his intentions were good, he may have been up to some *chicanery*.

> **[Chicanery](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chicanery?s=t)** [shi-key-nuh-ree, chi-] *noun*, plural chi·can·er·ies.
>
> 1. trickery or deception by quibbling or sophistry:
>
> *He resorted to the worst flattery and chicanery to win the job.*
>
> 2. a quibble or subterfuge used to trick, deceive, or evade.